# I get "Assertion failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push` " when querying API

Tags: json, node.js, rest, ember.js, express

I must have read every question on stack overflow regarding my issue and have not found a solution.
I am very new to Ember and Node so please bear with me.

The server responds with this format:

```
{
"_id" : "53fddf59d72f9b4d3a3e164a"
"about" : [
    {"from" : "foo"},
    {"text" : "bar"},
    ... ]
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
App.About = DS.Model.extend({
    from : DS.attr('string'),
    text : DS.attr('string'),
    ...
}
```

Adapter & serializer:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:3000'
});

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

And my route:

```
App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('about');
    }
});
```

Using handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
    <p>{{from}}</p>
</script>
```

The route will render, but the console gives the error:

> DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:3285
>   DEBUG: Ember      : 1.3.0 ember.js:3285
>   DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.5 ember.js:3285
>   DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 ember.js:3285
>   DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2 ember.js:3285
>   DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:3285
>   generated -> route:application Object {fullName: "route:application"} ember.js:3285
>   **Assertion failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push` ember.js:3285**
>   generated -> controller:about Object {fullName: "controller:about"} ember.js:3285
>   Transitioned into 'about'

What am I doing wrong?!

---

Update:

Have accepted Kingpin2k's answer even though this was not the exact format I ended up using. See the comments for details.

Comment: Just a guess, but try putting the `primaryKey` specification into a `AboutSerializer`.

Comment: @torazaburo shouldn't the ApplicationSerializer apply it to the whole application?

Comment: I don't know, try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format should have the type plural, and the id on the individual records.

```
 {
  "abouts" : [
    {
     "from" : "foo",
     "text" : "bar",
     "_id" : "53fddf59d72f9b4d3a3e164a"
    },
    {
     "from" : "foo2",
     "text" : "bar2",
     "_id" : "53fddf59d72f9b4d3a3e164k"
    },
    ... ]
 }
```

Comment: Ok so I changed my api to return json in exactly the same format as above. Still however I get the error `Assertion failed: You must include an id in a hash passed to 'push'.` Am I missing something in the serialiser? Or is the model thats wrong?

Comment: Does Ember require that the root object has an idea?

Comment: I think it's unhappy about you mixing the JSONAdapter and RESTSerializer, try using the RESTAdapter and RESTSerializer, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1011/edit,  Also you have the same primary key twice.

Comment: When I use RESTSerializer I get 'Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property id of undefined'. Also I have no duplicate ids, think you were looking at your answer above?

Comment: Yes, indeed I was looking at my answer ;)  Either way, did you look at the example, my guess would be you still have json that isn't properly formatted.

Comment: Indeed the json format was the issue. In the end I'm accepting a solution without the RESTAdapter and simply return `Ember.$.getJSON()` in when I extend the route. This way ember has no trouble using a object in the format `{ firstKey: "foo", secondKey: "bar", ... }` If I wasn't writing the API for this project though, I don't know what I would have done. @Kingpin2k Do you have under suggestions to better understand the the adapter and serializer classes? I've read throughout the documentation several times, but I'm missing more complex documentation (for something other than blogs)

Comment: @Kingpin2k I'm accepting your answer since the issue in essence was the json format

Comment: I have the same issue but I can't seem to solve the problem since my JSON is already in the format recommended above =/